# How to create, load and use sprite sheets in allegro 5?

Tags: allegro

I'm now familiar with allegro. But now allegro learning leads me to learn sprite sheets for my character animations.

This time I want some help on how to create, load and use the sprite sheets in allegro 5.

I'm using Dev c++ in windows PC. And without network connection(thought I should specify).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a spritesheet is just a matter of creating an image in the art program of your choice, divided up into rectangular regions. For the sake of this example, lets say each region in your spritesheet is 32x32 pixels.

To load the spritesheet, just use [`al_load_bitmap`](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.2.1.1/graphics.html#al_load_bitmap)
There is an example [here](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Basic_tutorial_on_loading_and_showing_images).

To draw 'sprites', you can use [`al_draw_bitmap_region`](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.2.1.1/graphics.html#al_draw_bitmap_region) and tell it what subsection of the spritesheet to draw.

Assuming our `spritesheet` is divided up into 32x32 pixel rectangles and `x, y` is the location you want to draw the sprite at:

`al_draw_bitmap_region(spritesheet, 0, 0, 32, 32, x, y)` would draw the 'first sprite' (from the very top-left corner of the sheet),

`al_draw_bitmap_region(spritesheet, 32, 0, 32, 32, x, y)` would draw the sprite just to the right of the first one, and so forth...

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice @rcorre . But when I use it in my program in a loop then the animations become slower and slower every time I use it... What to do now..??

Comment: Its hard to say without more information. You may want to ask another question with a minimal code sample demonstrating your problem

Comment: By any chance, are you loading the bitmaps every single time you draw the animation? That is a common beginner mistake. You should load once and store bitmaps in pointers.